# Delphi isn't writing my file header properly

Tags: delphi, file-io, bitmap

I thought instead of using TImage with an 8bit BMP I'd save my own Bitmap - which I have done with Delphi a few times before. But for some reason I cannot figure out, the first two bytes of the file is always written as four bytes!
My record for the header is

```
type
 BitmapH = Record
  head : WORD;
  filesize : DWORD;
  reserved : DWORD;
  bmpoffset : DWORD;
  bmpheadersize : DWORD;
  width : DWORD;
  height : DWORD;
  planes : WORD;
  bpp : word;
  comp : longint;
  bmdatasize : longint;
  hres : longint;
  vres : longint;
  numofcolors : longint;
  importantcolors : longint;
  palette : array[0..1023] of byte;
 end;
```

I've tried even changing it to a 2 byte array still no go. Even with it changed to just head : byte; it still writes 1 byte then pushes junk to the next 3. I must be missing something simple!

Here's how I am writing the file header -

```
var BM : file of BitmapH;
var BMD : file of byte;
var header : BitmapH;
var i : integer;
var test : byte;
begin

  AssignFile(BM, 'd:\test.bmp');
  Rewrite(BM);

  header.head := 19778;
//  header.head[1] := 'M';
  header.filesize := 2102;
  header.reserved := 0;
  header.bmpoffset := 1080;
  header.bmpheadersize := 40;
  header.width := 32;
  header.height := 32;
  header.planes := 1;
  header.bpp := 8;
  header.comp := 0;
  header.bmdatasize := 1024;
  header.hres := 100;
  header.vres := 100;
  header.numofcolors := 0;
  header.importantcolors := 0;

  for i := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    header.palette[i*4] := getBvalue(palette[i]);
    header.palette[(i*4) + 1] := getBvalue(palette[i]);
    header.palette[(i*4) + 2] := getBvalue(palette[i]);
    header.palette[(i*4) + 3] := 0;
  end;

  Write(BM, header);
```

Sorry for the crudeness, it's just a test :)

Any help is appreciated!

PS - The reason for not using TImage to save is because I am changing the palette on the fly which seems like a hassle to edit via TImage.

Comment: Why not just use the types already defined in Windows, like TBitmapFileHeader and TBitmapInfoHeader? Then, they'll have the right structure, and the field names will match what everyone else knows them as, so you'll be able to communicate about them better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`packed record`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types) to avoid the default memory alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Add **packed** keyword to record to indicate that it's content should not be aligned:

```
BitmapH = packed Record
```